# Power of HTML5?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, html5

HTML5 is becoming more and more popular everyday. Many great online applications are now being created and described as pure HTML5 apps. (Like [Muro](http://muro.deviantart.com/))

But I don't understand what is exactly so cool about HTML5?

As far as I understand, it just adds few features for graphics that make good alternative for jQuery or Flash.

But still, it is not a programming language and it can not be used in any way to create an application, right? Still, every of the advertised HTML5 applications have only interface drawn by HTML5 and CSS3, but the core and logic of any application is still written in something more advanced, like JavaScript (at least part that runs on the client side in the browser).

Or is there something else about HTML5 that I just didn't find?

Comment: It is just nearing the peak of hype: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hype_cycle

Comment: Perhaps you're just underestimating how much people despise Flash?

Comment: I never used it, but I know how Apple hates it and I believe that they have good reasons for that, mostly concerning security.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 hype as native app replacement - reliable analysis and sources](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127215/html5-hype-as-native-app-replacement-reliable-analysis-and-sources) and of [Relevance of HTML5: Is now the time?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/23455/relevance-of-html5-is-now-the-time)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The buzzword HTML5 isn't being used "properly" these days. Now HTML5 includes WebGL, WebSockets, Canvas, LocalStorage, etc... HTML5 is actually just the newest revision of the HTML markup language.

HTML5 (the definition now used by people to encompass many new web technologies) isn't meant to replace JQuery. JQuery is a JavaScript library meant to provide a single, unifying API across all browsers for DOM manipulation, among other things. JQuery is still being used in HTML5 applications.

HTML5 exposes a ton of new APIs to JavaScript which is where HTML5 applications reside in. That's where you program all your logic (apart from presentation and markup).

HTML5 is powerful as it's a combination of lots of different web technologies.

Comment: Here's a [diagram](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/HTML5-APIs-and-related-technologies-by-Sergey-Mavrody.png) I found on Wikipedia of various HTML5 APIs and technologies which I think helps add to your point.

Comment: That is a great diagram. Thanks a lot. And does it mean that JavaScript is integrated in any existing modern web browser, including mobile browsers?

Comment: Of those new APIs, I would guess most people like the Canvas. Ability to draw anything on the web page, using just JavaScript (no applets, no flash). And it's surprisingly fast.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that it works, the main advantage is that it is an open standard un-encumbered by licensing, restrictive copyrights, patents etc.

Proprietary technologies such as Adobe Flash do not sit well with the ethos of the Web, which from the very beginning has been based on open standards which any group or organisation is free to implement and use. Furthermore the W3C standards procedure is open and democratic so anyone with a vested interest can have some influence on the standard.

The downside is that the standards process is s l o w. This is especially true for animated graphics where numerous non-standard technologies became available before W3C even decided there should be a standard. Thus FLASH become a de-facto standard for showing video etc. although with its numerous versions, security holes and locked down licensing it really was not a very good standard.